# Change configuration on demand without restarting container

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration

Spring MVC + Java 8 + Tomcat 8 stack

I am maintaining my configuration in yaml and flattening the properties using Spring's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and maintaining the configuration in a bean.

Today, it has a inherent problem as I am required to restart the server whenever there is a change to the YML files.

I believe there are ways to refresh the bean without restart, but my main concern is how to do in fail safe manner.

Lets assume, there was a request and that time the config was A, and then we refresh the configuration so now its B, but if any subsequent user request was dependent on the configuration, then it will blow up.

Answer (score 1):

Add this configuration to your servlet-context.xml to catch property changes on the fly:

```
<context:property-placeholder
    location="file:${A_CONFIG_LOCATION}/configuration.properties" />

<beans:bean id="propertiesLoader"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">

    <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="1" />
    <beans:property name="basenames">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>file:${A_CONFIG_LOCATION}/configuration
            </beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

And then you can read property values like this:

```
@Component
public class PropertiesReader {

    private String  value         = "some_default_value";

    @Autowired
    MessageSource   propertiesLoader;

    public String getValue() {
        value = propertiesLoader.getMessage("configuration.value", null, null);
        return value;
    }


}
```